# Add Pandas dataframe name as a column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to add the name of my dataframe as a column in my dataframe.

I'm trying:

```
DF_NAME = pd.read_csv('CSV_LOCATION', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
DF_NAME['NAME'] = DF_NAME.NAME
```

Any pointers appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `DF_NAME['NAME'] = 'DF_NAME'` ?

Comment: I should clarify: the column name should be 'NAME' and the rows in the 'NAME' column should be the name of the dataframe.

Comment: Make 'DF_NAME' a string and load your DataFrames into a dictionary (`dfs['DF_NAME'] = pd.read_csv(...)`) In Python an object can have multiple names so to get the name of the DataFrame you would need to hack the globals which is not a good method.

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple dataframes and that causes the issue, consider using `dict` instead of variables and it will make it much easier to achieve your goal.

Example:

```
my_frames = {}

my_frames['DF_NAME'] = pd.read_csv('CSV_LOCATION', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")

for k, v in my_frames.items():
    my_frames[k] = v.assign(Name = k)
```

Answer (score 1):

A DataFrame object doesn't have an attribute called NAME. So, you have to create it first, using `DF_NAME.NAME = 'MyDF'` or `DF_NAME['NAME'] = 'MyDF'`.